# Is there any way to know when an activity launched completely?

Tags: android, android-activity

I wrote a script to simulate the user actions. The workflow is, for example, first tap an icon, launch an activity. Then do other actions.
The question is , I don't know the exact time that the activity launched completely. At present, I use `sleep` to make my script wait.
Is there any way to know when an activity launched completely?

Comment: That depends, is it an activity that you have control over? So you are able to write code in it? And where do you run the script from?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is your final task is to run something after activity is launched... do this

First method called from activity is `onCreate()` , Hence we can say completing the `onCreate()` system calls `onStart()` which calls `onResume()` method... as `onResume()` completes you can say your activity is launched properly...

If you are not going to override `onStart()` or `onResume()` what I am going to describe can be written as last statements of `onCreate()`. That's I usually do when I don't need `onStart()` or `onResume()`.

You can create an object of `Handler`. Like

`Handler handler = new Handler();`

Handler has a method `postDelayed()` that is called some times after the creating and launching is finished.

call it like

`handler.postDelayed(runnable,timeInMilliSeconds);`

after all the processes finish, application will wait for `timeInMilliSeconds`ms to start the process defined in `run` method of `runnable` provided in `postDelayed` .....

Thus

If your task is to know when the launching is finished the answer is: at the end of `onResume()` called from your `onStart()` ....

If you want to perform some action use `handler.PostDelayed()` method and keep `timeInMilliSeconds` very low... [between 1 to 10].

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what exactly you want to do when the activity started. But normally everyones requirement is to find width of a view or something to do with the UI. The thing is, onCreate is called before the UI is drawn so nothing related to the UI that involves measuring can be done here. For that we can use a global layout listener.

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = outerLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        outerLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        //This is executed once the layout is drawn. AFAIK this is as close as it gets
        to when the activity is started.
    }
});
```